# How To Insert , Update multiple checkboxes to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a form with  80 checkboxes.. Its a options form for car..  For example

**Colour:** `black , red , white , yellow`  etc..   How should i design my database for many options?

should i create 80 column in table? or  use implode() and save in a one column or multiple rows?    but  when i need i should update it...

```
Car_id |  black | red | white | yellow  |..... | option80 |
1            true     true
```

how should i do ? Thank you for your help

Comment: You *should* [**normalze**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database tables.

Comment: A table for car that has a column linked to a table called color, this way 1 column has a relationship with another table and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out normalization. That might help.

Anyway, to help you get on your way, here's a basic setup for that.

```
+-----TABLE CAR------+
ID
NAME

+-----TABLE COLOR------+
ID
COLOR

+-----TABLE CAR_COLOR------+
CAR_ID
COLOR_ID
```

This makes sure you have a link table between CAR and COLOR

Hope this was helpful

Comment: how can i update it ? maybe there are 40 options checked?  its  gonna be  car_id 1 , color_id 1  |   car_id 1 , color_id 2

Comment: exactly, that's how the link table is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to do in the future selection of the item by color, then it is better to create related tables:

```
table of cars (car_id, car_name)

table of colors (color_id, color_name)

table of relation colors and cars (car_id, color_id)

(sql - join)
```

And if you plan to just use as a characteristic of the car, then one cell with all the flowers separated "|" and when you create insert in the database use implode(), and select from the database explode()